# What things to care of when I Change Locale=en to Locale=ar(Arabic) in Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, locale

My Web application is in Spring MVC and Mysql.

Up-till now the application is support to only `Locale en`. Now i want to provide support to Locale ar(Arabic).
When I Change of `Locale=en` to `Locale=ar`(Arabic) then what are things to take care of in Spring MVC Application.

In My database i have used `collation:utf8 utf8_unicode_ci`

Is any change required in database when I change locale?

Comment: It really depends on design of your application so far. Is your application is already supporting (or designed to support) internationalization? If not, you many need to change quite a few things, like moving all your messages to respective props files etc. One obvious thing is you need to append `?characterEncoding=UTF-8` to you db url.

Comment: i have already appended ?characterEncoding=UTF-8 to you db url.and we are using respective prop files for messages.

Comment: Then it should work as expected, even if you face some issue, I think you should be able to fix it easily.

Comment: @Rp, Is any chances of time zone issues?

Comment: If you already taken care, like displaying times in their respective timezones, NO otherwise, YES you need to account for that.